# How to declare a function that takes a function with a function as an argument?

Tags: c++, time, function-pointers

Sorry for the long-winded and confusing title! Here's my problem: I'm trying to write a function to output the time that another function takes. Normally I'd just pass in the function and its arguments but in this instance, the functions I'm trying to time themselves take functions as arguments.

For a concrete example, I'm trying to get this to work:

```
void foo(void (*f) (T*)){
  ...function stuff...
}

                  --------not sure what this should be
                 | 
void runWithTime(void (*f) (void (*g) (T*))){
  f(g)
}

//runWithTime(foo);
```

I want to be able to call `runWithTime(foo)`, but I'm not sure what the type `runWithTime`'s argument should be.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine, what error are you getting?

Comment: "g was not declared in this scope" when I call `f(g)`

Comment: `void (*) (T*)` instead of `void (*g) (T*)` I think

Comment: you're probably better off just making it a template though

Comment: Well, where do you declare `g`. In the body of `runWithTime`?

Comment: @StephenLin: You're allowed to give function parameters names.

Comment: well, it's pointless...anyway @BenjaminKovach what I think you want is: `runWithTime(void (*f) (void (*) (T*)), void (*g) (T*))`...you have to pass the function taking the function and the function to pass to that function separately, unless `g` is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Perhaps I'm going about this wrong. I might be trying to pattern-match or something. `g` is supposed to be the function that `f` takes as a parameter.

Comment: Post-edit: Where you had `... more function stuff ...` you now have invalid code. What's the `g` in the body of `runWithTime` supposed to refer to?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Stephen answered my question right after I saw what the issue was. `g` was supposed to be the function of type `void (*) (T*)` to use, I was just naming it in the absolute wrong spot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `g` has to refer to something, perhaps you just need to declared it: `void runWithTime(void (*f)(void (*)(T*))) { void g(T*); f(g); }`

Comment: @BenjaminKovach the template answer given below is more flexible and clearer, though, it'll work with any function and any argument

Comment: @StephenLin: The issue was that he was trying to refer to something undeclared. What makes you think that he needs a template?

Comment: @CharlesBailey sorry, I meant that "@BenjaminKovach" instead...there's just no reason to go through the trouble of making a function for one particular type signature when you could do it for any function taking one argument just as easily, that's all...in any case the function and its argument has to be passed separately (which was the main issue, yes, but it was obfuscated by function pointer syntax)...generally the C++ approach is to prefer templates over function pointers, since they can be generalized to functors while function pointers cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
template<typename T>
auto runWithTime0(T _func) -> decltype(_func())
{
  startTimer();
  _func();
  endTimer();
}

template<typename T, typename P1>
auto runWithTime1(T _func, P1 _arg1) -> decltype(_func(_arg1))
{
  startTimer();
  _func(_arg1);
  endTimer();
}

// ...etc
```

You can do something similar with boost::bind and what not as well, but if that's not available the above should do the trick.

**Edit:** added return value, which will work if your compiler supports c++11 (VC2010/2012, g++4.7 or higher I believe)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `runWithTime(foo)` you're passing it a pointer to a function, which is the `f` parameter, but you're not supplying `g`, so you can't call `f(g)` ... what is that meant to do?

To make your life simpler use some typedefs:

```
// A pointer to a function that takes a single T* argument
typedef void (*func_ptr)(T*);

void foo(func_ptr f){
  ...function stuff...
}

// A pointer to a function that takes a single func_ptr argument
typedef void (*funcfunc_ptr)(func_ptr);

void runWithTime(funcfunc_ptr f, func_ptr g){
  f(g)
}
```

Now it should be obvious you need to pass two arguments to `runWithTime`, e.g. `runWithTime(foo, NULL)` or `runWithTime(foo, bar)` where `bar` is a function with the signature `void bar(T*)`

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, I wrote some code for almost exactly the same purpose semi-recently. What I came up with was this:

```
template <class F, class T>
void timer(F f, T &t, std::string const &title) { 
    unsigned count;
    clock_t start = clock();
    result = f(t, 'N');
    clock_t stop = clock();
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(30) << title << "\tResult: " << result;
    std::cout << "\tTime: " << double(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
}
```

Use was like: `timer(function1, infile, "Running function 1");`